# Why is Canada Free Press prohibited?

Tags: bug, status-norepro

Does SE have a problem with Canadians?

@Felix Goldberg [solved an interesting puzzle](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/11932/1401). I tried to wikifiy the source, but StackExchange informs me that links to CanadaFreePress are not allowed.  Can someone explain why?  Does StackExchange discriminate against Canadians?  Or is SE afraid of the Free Press?

*tongue firmly in cheek; I just wish the error message **explained** rather than **asserting***.

Update: the link is there, but I tried to insert the link into the answer, rather than leaving it dangling out in the wild. I would quote the error, but it was a red popup box that can't be copied/pasted. It said roughly, "Links to canadafree press are prohibited".

Comment: The link is in there now, you should quote the exact term that was the problem in this meta post. The reason a domain is blocked is almost certainly that they used to spam the site.

Comment: Was completely unable to duplicate the reported issue, so I really can't help. Perhaps it just has a problem with **you**? :-)